# How to copy a sparse file using scp?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

Do we have any option in `scp` that I could copy a sparse file ?

The following command works with `ssh`, But I am looking for an option in `SCP` which copies a sparse file.

```
tar -Szcf - /home/myself/test/ | \
  ssh myself@myserver 'tar -C /home/myself/test_scp -zvxf -'
```

Answer (score 17):

`scp` doesn't support sparse files. Use `rsync` instead.

```
rsync -aS /home/myself/test/ myself@myserver:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Rsync does via ssh. But I am looking exactly for sparse file copy using 'scp' command

Comment: rsync can, unfortunately, be lots slower in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it also through SFTP, though I don't know any SFTP client supporting that feature.

**Update**: I have added that feature into the development version of my Perl module [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/module/SALVA/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.72_02/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm). In example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

@ARGV == 3 or die <<EOU;
Usage:
  sparse_put <host> <src> <dst>

my ($host, $src, $dst) = @ARGV;

$s = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, autodie => 1);
$s->put($src, $dst, sparse => 1);
```

Comment: will this be possible using the native SFTP client in Linux ? Do u have the syntax for the sftp command ?

Comment: no, but see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

You can add

> --sparse=always

to **scp** command, but it will copy regular file on the other side (no sparse).

Answer (score -1):

Just add this option to scp:

```
--sparse=always
```

It's listed on cp man page, but also works for scp.

Comment: where is it documented that this works? For me it isn't `unknown option -- -`